# What does Buddhism teach regarding Cyber-Bullying?

Tags: karma, technology

Refer to [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIV5k.jpg) about the Cyber Bully, it causes a huge spike of cyber bully over a recent decade due to social media. It's seem getting more and more serious.

[source about cyberbully](https://firstsiteguide.com/cyberbullying-stats/)

What does Buddhism teach regarding Cyber Bullying?

Comment: Very low quality question, hence the downvotes i assume. Likewise questions like rhis, eg 'What does Buddhism teach about cervical radiculopathy or about the new tesla engine? Followed by a body of info about CR and the engine complete with pictures.. it's difficult for me to believe this is posted in good faith.

Comment: @7years and yet it isn't obviously spam

Comment: As i see it, It should 've been removed immediately and user suspended already because note he persistently posts low quality questions, in a similar format and doesn't interact with other users when asked questions. I mean if you are waiting for sock puppet accounts to identify themselves explicitly and for trolling to be more obvious, it's probably not going to happen.

Comment: I think moderators should use their judgement and err on side of protecting the community because it's what u have power for. It's wrong if you are going to err on the side of suspect posters

Comment: It can be closed as a duplicate of bullying questions.

Comment: Also edited the question's body to remove most of the parts which are off-topic. FWIW I don't think the OP has the intention to spam or any other malicious intent.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the teaching is don't bully others and let others have their peace and ease.

> I have heard that on one occasion the Blessed One was staying near
> Sāvatthī at Jeta's Grove, Anāthapiṇḍika's monastery. And on that
> occasion, a large number of boys on the road between Sāvatthī & Jeta's
> Grove were hitting a snake with a stick. Then early in the morning the
> Blessed One adjusted his under robe and — carrying his bowl & robes —
> went into Sāvatthī for alms. He saw the large number of boys on the
> road between Sāvatthī & Jeta's Grove hitting the snake with a stick.
>
> Then, on realizing the significance of that, the Blessed One on that
> occasion exclaimed:
>
> Whoever hits with a stick
> beings desiring ease,
> when he himself is looking for ease,
> will meet with no ease after death.
>
> Whoever doesn't hit with a stick
> beings desiring ease,
> when he himself is looking for ease,
> will meet with ease after death.
> [Ud 2.3](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.2.03.than.html)

The same thing in [Dhammapada 131 - 132](https://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=131).

Answer (score 1):

Cyber bullying is a nasty issue. Social media mixes us all together even with others who would hurt us, making it hard for us to find a refuge. The technology is trying to change and adapt as it can, but it will take some time. And during that time, we can simply remember what the Buddha said.

> [MN8:12.7](https://suttacentral.net/mn8/en/sujato#mn8:12.7): ‘Others will speak divisively, but here we will not speak divisively.’

Answer (score -1):

Cyber bullying is a fictional concept created by people who didn't understand the meme and in turn are attempting to destroy decades old culture (internet culture)

Really there wouldn't be a Buddhist view on such a trivial thing as it neither falls into harmful actions or incorrect speech, even audio speech is up for debate whether it relays to incorrect speech. It is impossible to harm someone via text on a screen, if this was a case any written symbol could be seen as a negative action from drawing a straight line to a geometric shape and many books would also be "bullying" others just those people are not reading those books at the present moment to notice they are being bullied. Anyone who thinks they are being "bullied" just wasn't taught how to use a computer properly and need to learn how to press ALT+TAB or ALT+F4.

Also your inconsequential chart isn't really representing the fact that after 07-10 there was a mass influx of normies onto the internet (because of social media) who use terrible "search engines" like google and have no idea of the cyberbullying meme other than just as a word that other people who have no idea about the internet seemed to take as a real phenomena.

Either way this post has nothing to do with Buddhism and seems to be some sort of political/social issue that does not belong here at all.